# how to change the videoview playing video from portrait to landscape mode programmatically on clicking a button

Tags: android, orientation, android-videoview

I now have video view which is in portrait mode and while video is playing, on clicking the button video view should keep playing the video and at the same time it should change to the landscape mode.i have searched many but couldn't get answer. please help me. i have tried the `setRotation()` method for video view but it changes the video view alone but still video played in portrait mode ... how to achieve this? I need landscape mode only after clicking the button ...

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but actually i am having a layout containing videoview fits the half and above the videoview one button and below that having three buttons. when i do the above one as you suggested it turns the whole layout to landscape but i need video view alone to landscape mode...how to do this

Comment: Do you mean, Button is in portrait mode and VideoView is in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. According to what i have understood from your question and comment on `Palak's` answer. what u need is on `landscape` mode you want only video view in screen & portrait mode u have `VideoView` along with 3 button.

Solution:

What is best thing u can do is make a folder in `\res` name `layout-land` & make an .xml with same name.

now this `xml` will execute when u r in `landscape` mode.

& then try `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

I think this might helps u.

Comment: but for that i need to load once again the video know..but i need to play the video not from the start...

Comment: ok that you can handle. there are several method available like `getCurrentPosition()` you can use it.

Comment: but if i need to use that , videoview takes some time for its initialisation....:-( and then it plays the seekposition sometime later...:-(